# Parse iOS NSInternalInconsistencyException after User Logout and New User Login

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse iOS SDK and sporadically getting the NSInternalInconsistencyException 'User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp'. I've read a lot about this error, and it seems to come up when apps try to save a ref to another user on the iOS side (instead of Cloud Code) or when apps try to modify an unautheticated user. I am attempting to do neither of these -- I'm able to trigger it when trying to save a string property of the logged in user. As I mentioned, this error occurs sporadically, so it's very difficult to track down, but I wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions.

When I change my [currentUser saveInTheBackground] calls to the synchronous [currentUser save] I do not seem to see this error. And to reiterate, it only occurs after signing out with one user and signing in with another, but does not occur with any type of consistency. If the crash the app and reopen, I'm able to save for that user.

I've found a similar threads around the web referencing a similar issue: 
   [Parse SDK on iOS: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707282/parse-sdk-on-ios-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-user-cannot-be-sa)
   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/UZ1ywdpUFVQ

I'm using the iOS SDK 1.6.5 (this error also popped up on 1.6.3) and have parse localDataStore enabled.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Also, not sure if this is the right place to post -- please let me know if not. I tried the Parse Google Group a few days ago, but have not received any responses and am don't know if it's a bug, so decided the FB bugs site was not a good place to post.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Allen No, not yet.. I'm going to try updating my Parse to a newer version and will again try to find the origin but am still occasionally getting it. Will update with my findings if they are fruitful

Comment: please do, we're running into this problem, and it seems to be a Parse bug. We actually realize we started encountering it when implementing ACL controls

Comment: I've been testing out the latest Parse iOS SDK today and it seems to have fixed my issues (usually the bug would come up on sign in/out and it's now not showing itself at all) -- I'd try checking it out (https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads) and let me know how it goes!

Comment: For future reference, I think I found the root cause of it. If I log out with of a PFUser session, login with a new user, then save a pointer to the logged out user in newly signed in user's object, I see this error. Not sure if it's a bug or expected behavior.